# Why I am not asked [i] times to input a string?

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently doing CS - PSET2, and I wrote the code below.

Everything is working, but now that I am re-reading it, I don't understand why.

The doubt is with line 11: `if(isdigit(argv [1][i]))`.

Let's say I write `"35"`, first char is a number, so loop is true and it starts --> I have to write a string (Line 16).

Now program will check the second char, "5", it is a number, true --> I have to write a string again theoretically.

But why not? Why don't I get double results for everything?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc , string argv [])
{
    if (argc == 2 && isdigit(argv [1]))
    {
        int n = strlen(argv [1]);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(isdigit(argv [1][i]))
            {
                 string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
                 int key = atoi(argv[1]);
                 int l = strlen(plaintext);
                 for(int p=0; p <l; p++) 
                 if isupper(plaintext[p])
                 {
                     printf("%c", (((plaintext[p] - 'A') + key) % 26) + 'A');
                 }
                 else if islower(plaintext[p])
                 {
                     printf("%c", (((plaintext[p] - 'a') + key) % 26) + 'a');
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     printf("%c", plaintext[p]) ;
                 }
                 return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Nope\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Nope\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int main (int argc , string argv [])` is suspicious, but ok if `string` is an alias for `char*`. But `isdigit(argv [1])` should not even compile, as `isdigit()` takes an `int` not a `char*`.  And `int key = atoi(argv[1]);` will convert the entire `"35"` to an int `35`, is that what you really want? Or did you want to convert only the individual digits `3` and `5`? Because `atoi()` can't do that without putting them each into a `char[2]` array with a null terminator.

Comment: @RemyLebeau fyi, `string` is definitely aliased as `char*`. It's one of the many (non) "helpful" things that `cs50.h` brings to the party that ultimately utterly confuse students new to C.

Comment: Are you compiling as C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  The C++ language has `std::string` and the definition is in `<string>`.  The C language only has array of characters.

Comment: You should **always** have braces after `for` loops.  It makes reading easier and coding easier.  See your `for (int p= 0` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `return 0;` statement inside the `if` that checks for a digit.  This will cause it return before it can loop again.  Just get rid of that return.